# Detect bluetooth scanner and read barcode when available in Win RT

Tags: visual-studio-2015, barcode-scanner, winrt-component

I am able to scan a bar code using Bluetooth scanner on a button click in VS 2015, but I want to write a code, which would detect my bluetooth device any time, when I try to scan any barcode and not only on a button click.

Answer (score 1):

Using nearly the same code you have in your button, you might :
- Connect once to your device
- Read continuously the Bluetooth stream to get the barcodes in a task

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(true
    {
         //Read your BT stream
    }
});
```